# smarty: better let it doing the hard part or better serving it php-precompiled html?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, smarty, template-engine

I was wandering.. If, say, I have to build a menu, or say, a group of specs sheets based on an array of product data.. In other words, if I have to render an array, what is better (from a performance point of view):

a. build all the html in php (say in a controller) and pass to smarty the variable where I saved the html

b. do nothing in php, pass the array to smarty and build the relevant html within the template?

Comment: From a performance point of view it probably does'nt matter once smarty has compiled the template the first time, as it converts it to php code. From a practical point of view... you are supposed to use smarty to separate logic from presentation. If you want to create html code with php, just don't use smarty.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'm using prestashop so I quite HAVE to use smarty, and I was wandering if it was more heavy for processors, a straight php (obviously supposed to be well crafted) html conversion or a smarty rendering.
But, you are right, the point here should be separate logic from presentation. Still, in this case is a bit ambiguous at least for me, since if I pass the raw array and do all with smarty, I'll end up with logic in smarty (for doing loops, set first last even odd items and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smarty templates are compiled into PHP code the first time they are processed, so unless you are doing some particularly exotic processing which is hard to express in Smarty syntax, the chances are the performance will be very similar.

The question also sounds a lot like "premature optimisation": you are assuming in advance that something might be a performance issue, and spending energy "optimising" it before you have any measurable outcome. This energy would be better saved for later when you actually have some performance to measure, and can find which parts of the code can give you the biggest improvement.

Whether it is your choice or that of the application you are using, the idea of a templating language like Smarty is that it contains all your display logic, so moving display logic into the "controller" (which would presumably then also be a "view" in the MVC way of thinking) defeats the point of the separation.

If you really hate Smarty, you could presumably write your own "view" layer, which pre-processed all the output into HTML, and passed a single variable to the Smarty template, but I'm not sure that's what you're after.